# DatePickerDialog rendering issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using the following code to display a datepicker dialog:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
{
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
    {
    mDateOfJourney.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    if (mDateOfJourney.after(mCalendar) || mDateOfJourney.equals(mCalendar)) 
        {
        setJourneyDateView(mDateOfJourney);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.invalid_date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        dialog.show();
```

The output of this code has some rendering issues: It shows up like this:

[image]

Comment: Is this an emulator or some real device?

Comment: not clear, what is the issue here, what are those views below the data picker ?

Comment: This is an actual device- Nexus 5. Those views below the picker are my concern.I don't know what is brings them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picture above, the window's background is null. Look through your app's style definition. You might find this somewhere:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

Or else, you might have set the window's background to `null`: `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null)`.

The only theme I know that sets this attribute for you is `Theme.NoDisplay`. So, if you're not using this theme as a base (or as is), you will have to use a different theme.

Comment: Not just @null. If I set any background this happens. There is no need to set background on a dialog, so I removed it and sovled the problem. Thanks!